# apktool command in shell script does not execute from Java program

Tags: java, linux, shell

I wish to execute a simple bash Script from Java. This script is as follows:

```
cp /home/ashish/Downloads/apktool/apktool.jar /home/ashish/workspace/MyFirstApp/bin/apktool.jar

java -jar apktool.jar d -f MyFirstApp.apk

echo "Hello World"
```

The problem is only the cp command is executed and the last echo is executed. The second command doesn't execute. However, if I execute the second command from the command line, it runs well (the apk folder is created).

How can I make Java program execute the apktool command from the shell script ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my experience, I would say that Java is not very fond of being ran by means of script.
I did a quick google search. Try the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it looks perfect for this situation, in my opinion.

I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Process itself. My OS is CenTOS running Java SDK 1.6. But only Echo statements and a copy statement get executed. The command to decompile a .apk folder does not execute. Anyway, my colleague told me that's no longer needed for the application (can be done manually). So, although the issue doesn't bug me now, it still remains !